# How do I run qmake files?

Tags: ubuntu, qmake

I'm new to Linux and have just started using Ubuntu.

I'm trying to install QtScript Generator. Here is what it's README says:
Step 1:

> Build the generator: cd path/to/this/project/generator, qmake && make

Done.

Step 2:

> Run the generator (without arguments) This will generate C++ files in path/to/this/project/generated_cpp and documentation in path/to/this/project/doc

How do I run the generator file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There should be a new executable in your `path/to/this/project/generator` after `make`. Check it's name using `ls`. I think executables are coloured red in Ubuntu.

Comment: Assuming you have done the steps correctly, then there is an executable file as @prajmus said. To run it, just type `./generator`